# Single-file ASPX and LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, single-file

there's a CMS system and there's aspx page without backend file. I can add server code straight to the .aspx wrapped with `<script language="C#" runat="server">` tag. But compiler generates an error because I use LINQ in my code and I don't have `using System.Linq;` statement anywhere. And I can't add using inside .aspx file (error again). What should I do?

```
<%@ Page Inherits="MyPage" MasterPageFile="~/Master.master" %>
<script language="C#" runat="server">
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static List<string> GetA()
{
    MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext();

    var result = from a in db.A
                 select a;

    return result.ToList();

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add

```
<%@ Import Namespace = "System.Linq" %>
```

Above the code should work.

So final code should look like

```
<%@ Page Inherits="MyPage" MasterPageFile="~/Master.master" %>
<%@ Import Namespace = "System.Linq" %>
<script language="C#" runat="server">
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static List<string> GetA()
{
    MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext();

    var result = from a in db.A
                 select a;

    return result.ToList();

}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! Also System.Collections.Generic is required. Everything worked, great :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the `LINQ` namespace. You use the `import` declaration.

```
<%@ Page Inherits="MyPage" MasterPageFile="~/Master.master" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.Linq" %>
<script language="C#" runat="server">
...
```